# proving that a function has a third derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable and non-decreasing define $h(x)= e^{f'''(x)}$

i need to show that $h$ is differentiable and non-decreasing on $\mathbb R$. i know that i can use rules of derivatives to show that if $e^x$ is differentiable and $f'''(x)$ is differentiable then so is $h(x)$ but for for $f'''(x)$ is it as simple as saying that as $f(x)$ is differentiable $f'''(x)$ must be too? or am i missing something?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, then $f'$ is well defined, but $f''$ might not exist.

Comment: is there any way to find out whether f''' does actually exist then for h(x)?

Comment: The definition of $h(x)$ really doesn't say anything about $f$. The problem probably meant to say, at the very least, that $f$ was thrice differentiable, as otherwise the definition of $h$ may be invalid.